# How can I use Event class from Starling and Flash both in the same class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, starling-framework

While working with Starling, I am encountering this problem. It's important to use the flash Event sometimes.

```
import starling.events.Event;
import flash.events.Event ;
var _myFile_Fr:FileReference = new FileReference();
_myFile_Fr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
_myFile_Fr.load();
function onFileLoaded(event:Event ):void
{
  trace( event.target.data ) // <<<< compiler error:       


}
```

> Access of possibly undefined property data through a reference with
>   static type starling.events:EventDispatcher

I tried to use the full specification

```
function someEventHandler(event:flash.events.Event ):void
{
  ....
}
```

Also this way :

```
_myFile_Fr.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
_myFile_Fr.load();

function onFileLoaded(e:Event ):void 
{
    trace( e.target.data );
}
```

But the above doesnot work, and shows compile time error.

> access of undefined property Flash

Then what's the way out ?

Access of possibly undefined property data through a reference with static type starling.events:EventDispatcher. With flash.events.Event, it works fine.

Comment: include that error in question

Answer (score 1):

Problem is caused because the compiler thinks the event you want is a starling.events.Event.  Starling events have an attribute `target` but it (unlike flash events) is of the specific type `EventDispatcher` where flash is just a generic `Object`.  So when you look for `event.target.data` you are trying to look for the attribute `data` on a starling EventDispatcher object.  There is no data attribute in the EventDispatcher class, so it is throwing that error.
You need to be careful that when you have both starling.events.Event and flash.events.Event, you will need to specify exactly which one you are expecting (using its fully qualified name).

```
public function onLoad(event:flash.events.Event):void
```

or

```
public function onLoad(event:starling.events.Event):void
```

but not

```
public function onLoad(event:Event):void
```

unless you only imported either flash or starling events, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

from [starlling Doc](http://doc.starling-framework.org/current/starling/events/Event.html)

> Event objects are passed as parameters to event listeners when an
>   event occurs. This is Starling's version of the Flash Event class.

this class do all that `flash.events.Event` did before with its additional options. what would be the advantage of using import flash.events.Event in your case?

however

```
addEventListener(flash.events.Event.ADDED, handler);
function handler(e:flash.events.Event) {}
```

does not cause any error in regular way.

### Also <sup>from</sup> <sub>[starlling Doc](http://doc.starling-framework.org/current/starling/events/Event.html)</sub>

> In that case, you can subclass "Event" and add properties with all the
>   information you require.

Comment: I am trying to use e.target.data, for loading external data using FileReference class. But I get compiler error: 
Access of possibly undefined property data through a reference with static type starling.events:EventDispatcher. With flash.events.Event, it works fine.

Comment: addEventListener(flash.events.Event.ADDED, handler); causes compiler time error : access of undefined property Flash

Comment: @VishwasG try `e.data`, is it what you want?

Comment: I used e.data, but what is coming from FileReference is flash.events.Event, so it's not able to recognize e.data.  Anyway, the only way out i found was not to use the name of Event class anywhere.

Comment: @VishwasG so the only way, separate your loader class and only import flash.event,

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found was not to use Event class name anywhere. So, what worked for me is this :

```
import starling.events.Event;

var _myFile_Fr:FileReference = new FileReference();
_myFile_Fr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
_myFile_Fr.load();
function onFileLoaded(event):void //<< Don't use class name specification
{
  trace( event.target.data )  


}
```

Answer (score 0):

> access of undefined property Flash

You are correct that you need to use the fully-qualified class name `flash.events.Event`, but I suspect that you made a typo. Notice that the error says `Flash` where the first letter is upper-case. ActionScript is case sensitive so `Flash.events.Event` will not work. It must be `flash.events.Event` where `flash` is all lower-case.

```
import starling.events.Event;
import flash.events.Event;
var _myFile_Fr:FileReference = new FileReference();
_myFile_Fr.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
_myFile_Fr.load();
function onFileLoaded(event:flash.events.Event):void
{
    //see below for changes
}
```

> Access of possibly undefined property data through a reference with static type starling.events:EventDispatcher

This means exactly what it says. The `target` property of an event is typed as `EventDispatcher`. If you know that it's something more specific, you need to cast it, like this:

```
var file:FileReference = FileReference(event.target);
trace( file.data );
```